# The rigging did not work, one leg moved with the other

Tags: rigging

I did a rigging for a figure with the "parent-with Automatic weights", everything worked fine, the hands, the body, but when I came to do IK for the left leg, suddenly I notice that the right leg moves along with it. And I don't know how to fix it.
I'll note that I'm in the middle of a computer animation course, following step by step, so I don't have the tools and knowledge to fix this myself.

[image]

Comment: Hello please share your file

Comment: How can i add a file?

Comment: Please read the instructions here: https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: I have attached the file, hope it is ok

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the correct *Chain Length* for your IK bone (it needs to be 2 as it will influence 2 bones):

[image]

You also need to disable the *Deform* option of the control bone (it may be the problem here):

[image]

Once done you can symmetrize the armature (in the *Operator Box* you'll need to choose *+X to -X*):

[image]

Parent again *With Automatic Weights*, it will work fine:

[image]

Comment: thank you very very much!!
How beautiful that there are good people who invest for others and are ready to help!
I just have one more small question - now the legs really are separate, but it canceled all the IK - do I need to reset it or is there a way to preserve it?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, make sure that you symmetrize from +X to -X maybe?

Comment: That is - I can separate the character's legs, but the IK does not work, it seems to have been canceled, the leg is no longer yellow (as in IK in pose mode) and when I move it, it does not function as IK
If you easily find the problem, I'd be happy, and if not, then no big deal, I'll try to restart the IK.

Comment: Yes it looks like it's buggy in 3.6, you need to remove the right hand bones, then symmetrize, choose +X to -X, Ctrl Z in the Operator Box, it should work

Comment: Thank you! It works!